# HTML2Canvas render only what is visible on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas, pdf.js

i'm using HTML2Canvas to render two react components 
the problem is the the output of the document renders only what is visible on the screen,
so if the content of the component is short i can see all the content in the pdf , 
but if the content is long i nedd to scroll to the very top of the page to make it work or i need to zoom my navigation to 50% and then click print 
is there something wrong in my code :

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';

import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import Pie from './Pie.js';
import Post from './Post.js';

class Qu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    html2canvas(input)
    
      .then((canvas) => {
        
        let imgWidth = 208;
        let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      })
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
    
      <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4" style={{
                width: '100%',
                minHeight: '29.7cm',
                border: '1px #D3D3D3 solid',
                borderRadius: '5px',
                background: 'white',
                boxShadow: '0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
                size: 'A4',
                margin: 'auto'
            }}>
      
        <div><Pie /></div>
        <div><Pie /></div>
        <div className="mb5">
        <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
export default Qu;
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was : adding `window.scrollTo(0,0);` just before `html2canvas(input)`